# Implementing Calendar Control in Android

Tags: android, calendar

Here's my requirement :

Display Calendar (Monthly view) in the application.
Upon clicking on any cell in that widget, the daily events on the selected date will be displayed to the user in a list (below the calendar).

Is there a widget that can be used to display the calendar on a fragment?.

(
I did some searching online on this but I see people quipping that there is no native support for displaying calendar in Android which to me is a bit odd :(
)

Comment: I don't think that " there is no native support for displaying calendar in Android" the default date picker in android comes with attached calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this calendar for my project once. It many work for you too.

[But its really sad that there is no native support.](https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)